# Show me if all inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, html

I need to build such that all four inputs must be specified any such if there is nothing in the name so it must appear that the it is as trouble is that nothing is written in the name.

I want to want out of this is that I will not have to use such can just create a user or send an email but it must have written something in every input form.

I have done like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="kontakt_box">
                <span id="myhint" class="info_box_kontakt"></span>
                <br />
                <label>Navn<br /><input type="text" name="navn" class="new" placeholder="Navn"></label><br />
                <label>Efternavn<br /><input type="tel" name="efternavn" class="new" placeholder="Efternavn"></label><br />
                <label>Email<br /><input type="email" name="email" class="new" placeholder="Email"></label><br />
                <label>Tekst<br /><textarea name="tekst" cols="35" rows="10" class="new"></textarea></label><br />
                <label><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" class="new"></label>
            </form>
```

Javascript here:

```
document.kontakt_box.navn.onfocus=function() {
    document.getElementById('myhint').innerHTML = "Angive et navn!";
}
document.kontakt_box.navn.onblur=function() {
    document.getElementById('myhint').innerHTML = "";
}
//efternavn
document.kontakt_box.efternavn.onfocus=function() {
    document.getElementById('myhint').innerHTML = "Angive et efternavn!";
}
document.kontakt_box.efternavn.onblur=function() {
    document.getElementById('myhint').innerHTML = "";
}
//email
document.kontakt_box.email.onfocus=function() {
    document.getElementById('myhint').innerHTML = "Angive en email!";
}
document.kontakt_box.email.onblur=function() {
    document.getElementById('myhint').innerHTML = "";
}

document.kontakt_box.send = function(){
    alert('Husk noget tekst!');
    return false;
}
```

it's my first javasciprt task to a page, so you just better with me that there may be errors or you think it's strange made​​.

Comment: there are 1200 results for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+check+empty+input

Comment: @boyee007 everyone says to me that I first must learn javascript before I bother on to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last function may be something like this:

```
document.kontakt_box.onsubmit = function(){
    var navn = document.kontakt_box.navn.value,
        efternavn = document.kontakt_box.efternavn.value,
        email = document.kontakt_box.email.value,
        tekst = document.kontakt_box.tekst.value;
    if(!navn || !efternavn || !email || !tekst) {
        alert('Husk noget tekst!');
        return false;
    }
};
```

And add `;` afret each callback function assignment.

Working example here http://jsbin.com/enovex/1/edit

Comment: @deathApril `!!` before each variable is a simple way to cast no mater what to boolean. In this case it may be `null` or empty string which are casted to `false` or some non-empty string which is casted to `true`. The very first `!` just inverses the value of expression that follows it.